Setting up startup directory of dosemu on Ubuntu 24.04
I want dosemu to start at a custom directory instead of default C.
I have tried looking through /etc/dosemu/dosemu.conf for the option and the closest I found is $_hdimage . I tried
$_hdimage = "drives/* ~.dosemu/drive_c"
$_hdimage = "C:\code"

but dosemu won't start at all. Then I tried creating autoexec.bat in /.dosemu/drive_c which has the command CD \code but dosemu still won't change to the specified directory at startup. I've tried putting autoexec.bat in /.dosemu as well but still no luck.
What am I doing wrong?
